# Why does a partition need to be sorted prior to being reduced?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-partitioning

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35195101/which-runs-first-combiner-or-partitioner-in-a-mapreduce-job):

> As per hadoop definitive guide "Within each partition, the back-ground
>   thread performs an in-memory sort by key, and if there is a combiner
>   function, it is run on the output of the sort"

I thought a partition corresponds to one key, and thus a reduce task would reduce a bunch of values association with only one key. If there is only one key, isn't the partition already sorted?

After all, this answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22141631/what-is-the-purpose-of-shuffling-and-sorting-phase-in-the-reducer-in-map-reduce), to me seems to contradict the previous quote:

> Sorting saves time for the reducer, helping it easily distinguish when
>   a new reduce task should start. It simply starts a new reduce task,
>   when the next key in the sorted input data is different than the
>   previous, to put it simply.

It is saying that a reduce task is associated with one key, and since thre is one partition per reduce task, a partition is associated with one key. So how come there must be a sort within each partition if there is only one key?

Comment: Some datasets are not partitioned. Even within a partition, there may be non-partitioned keys. A typical partition might be a `date`. That `date` might be **part** of a key with another `id`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Can you expand more on "Even within a partition, there may be non-partitioned keys."? I'm not sure what you're saying (and that's on me).

Comment: The date is when something happened. The id is a customer id. A client id. A transaction id. A payment id. A payment method. Etc. Etc. Partitioning by the date does not mean date is the only key.

Comment: Okay, I see what you're saying now. However, isn't the reducer supposed to be commutative (let's say pre-sorted data was `b`, `a`, but now sorted data is `a`, `b`). If the iterator that the hadoop reducer was fed yielded `a` first then `b`, as opposed to opposite order, are there any situations where it is reasonable that the reducer gives a different result?

Comment: That's a requirement of Java's sort as well. When you partition a table in Hive, the partition is just a directory the HDFS files are organized by.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch What does that refer to? If you are talking about the reducer being commutative, doesn't that negate the need for a sort?